# Finding the position of exponents with non-zero coefficients

Tags: series-expansion

Suppose that an expansion can be obtained from

```
f[x_, y_] := QPochhammer[-x, x*y]*QPochhammer[-y, x*y]*QPochhammer[x*y, x*y]; 
CoefficientList[Series[f[q^3, q^3]^3 - 16 f[q^3, q^6]^3, {q, 0, 50}], q]
```

and the coefficient values are

```
{-15, 0, 0, -42, 0, 0, -84, 0, 0, -104, 0, 0, -90, 0, 0, -72, 0, 0, -88, 0, 
 0, -192, 0, 0, -180, 0, 0, -162, 0, 0, -120, 0, 0, -72, 0, 0, -184, 0, 0, 
 -168, 0, 0, -240, 0, 0, -208, 0, 0, -186}
```

This yields the expansion of the series as $-15 -42 q^3 -84 q^6 - 104 q^9 - 90 q^{12} \cdots$. Now, what is being sought is a method that can be used to yield the exponent of non-zero coefficients. For the case of the series shown the resulting values would be $\{ 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, \cdots \}$. What seems most reasonable is to use `Select` or `Position`.  Are these the better options and if so how can they be used to find/select the positions of non-zero data points or the exponents from the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Pick` for that:

```
f[x_,y_]:=QPochhammer[-x,x*y]*QPochhammer[-y,x*y]*QPochhammer[x*y,x*y];
cfs=CoefficientList[Series[f[q^3,q^3]^3-16 f[q^3,q^6]^3,{q,0,50}],q]

(* {-15,0,0,-42,0,0,-84,0,0,-104,0,0,-90,0,0,-72,0,0,-88,0,0,-192,0,0,-180,0,0,-162,0,0,-120,0,0,-72,0,0,-184,0,0,-168,0,0,-240,0,0,-208,0,0,-186} *)

Pick[Range[Length[cfs]]-1, Sign[Abs[cfs]], 1]

(* {0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
DeleteCases[
    Transpose[{Series[f[q^3, q^3]^3 - 16 f[q^3, q^6]^3, {q, 0, 50}][[3]],
                  Range[0, 48]}], {0, _}, {1}]

(*   {{-15, 0}, {-42, 3}, {-84, 6}, {-104, 9}, {-90, 12}, {-72, 15}, {-88, 
     18}, {-192, 21}, {-180, 24}, {-162, 27}, {-120, 30}, {-72, 
     33}, {-184, 36}, {-168, 39}, {-240, 42}, {-208, 45}, {-186, 48}}   *)
```